# How can I install Snow Leopard on a new iMac or install FCP6 on Lion?

Tags: macos, final-cut-pro

I'm in a situation where I purchased a new iMac and need to install my editing software (Final Cut Pro and After Effects).  Only thing is I have FCP 6 (Studio 2) and also FCP 7 (Studio 2) upgrade install DVDs and Lion won't install FCP 6 because it containts PPC code.

I'd like to either:

- install Snow Leopard on this computer, but I'm not sure if I need certain firmware drivers (anyone know where to get them and create a brand new Snow Leopard install DVD?)
- or, at the very least, I would like to be able to install my video software on Lion.

Comment: Please, describe what is FCP?

Comment: @Brain I suggest you to stay on Snow Leopard or upgrade your software to Intel version (or look for similar one). Don't remember about totally free updates from MacStore

Comment: @EirNym FCP = Final Cut Pro. A part of FCS (Final Cut Studio), which was discontinued recently.

Comment: [Compatible versions FCP for Lion](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4769) this link may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that new iMacs probably don't support Snow Leopard. Perhaps upgrading a Snow Leopard installation with all the apps you need already on it could work.

Well, I see 1 possibility: install Snow Leopard on an external HD (using a computer that supports Snow Leopard) with all the latest Apple updates, then install FCP. Once that's done, use Disk Utility or Carbon Copy Cloner to clone this external HD onto your iMac, then see first if it's starts and behaves correctly, then try the upgrade to Lion.

This is the jist of it, but if you need more instructions, let me know.

Comment: PPC Support has been removed in Lion completely, including upgrading.

Comment: Yes, I know. But FCP isn't a ppc app, looks like the installer is. This is why installing it in snow leopard first the upgrading the OS to lion should solve the problem. But does apple support FCP 6 or 7 on lion? That's a good question...

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to install Rosetta from a Snow Leopard Disk.

Do you have a Snow Leopard DVD install disk?

Run that, go to optional installs and install only Rosetta, reboot.

Now, you should be able to run the FCP 6 installer.

Comment: Are you saying Rosetta will run on a Lion machine?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to install Snow Leopard on a different computer. Install FCP6, then move the drive to your mac and do the upgrade.

Another solution would be to use Snow Leopard on a different Mac or on a virtual machine. Install FCP6, do a time machine save. Then restore applications from the time machine save on your mac (using the migration assistant).